# Nest app "login fail" incorrect user name or password

Tags: nest

I try to login and it says the username or password is incorrect... I changed the password through forgot password. Still says it.  I only have 1 username (email) and it was saved in my phone.

Help,

Comment: This is not really a forum for questions like this. But if I had to guess, you mistyped your password that you just changed. If you're typing it on a small cellphone screen keyboard, that's pretty easy to do, especially since you're probably required to use special characters in the password, and both caps/lowercase. Try changing the password on a PC & logging in on a PC. Or just be very careful when typing it on your phone's screen keyboard.

Comment: Thank you for the response.  I did make sure it was correct.  something else is going on.  Have a great day.  Dont know why Nest directed me to this site

Comment: Anthony, Stack Overflow is a site for asking questions about writing programs that operate on computers, tablets, phones, or embedded systems. It's not generally for asking questions about how to log on to websites or apps, unless logging on is somehow related to writing programs. Are you trying to use the Nest API and can't get it to log on? If not, then SO is not the best forum for asking this question. There may be other sites appropriate for that, perhaps superuser.com might be more appropriate.